# Calling PowerShell from PHP using IIS on network shared folders

Tags: php, powershell, iis

I have a simple PHP page that calls a simple PowerShell script.

test.php

```
<?php
    $runCMD = "powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File teste.ps1 2>&1";
    exec($runCMD,$out,$ret);
    if ($ret != 0) {
        echo "Could not run PowerShell.";
    } else {
        echo implode("\n",$out);
    }
?>
```

test.ps1

```
Write-Host "Just testing!"
```

When both files are placed in c:\inetpub\wwwroot, everything works fine. However, if I place them in a shared network folder (\\myserver\test, for example) and point IIS to this folder, php still works but it's not able to run the PowerShell script anymore. exec just returns error code 1 and the message "Could not run PowerShell" is printed. I am currently using PHP 7.4.1, IIS 10, Windows Server 2019 and PowerShell 5.1.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

App pool identities have very limited access to the local file system (and none outside the local computer). You will need to modify ACLs on the file system to give the identities the access they need.

try to set the domain user to the application pool identity.

use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon to check where access is being blocked.